# ASP.NET Merge: Virtual path 'obal.asax' is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, merge

I am doing a Web Deployment of my website and I have the merge assemblies property set to true.

For some reason I get the following error.

```
aspnet_merge : error occurred:
```

> An error occurred when merging assemblies: The relative virtual path `'Global.asax'` is not allowed here.

It seems to have something to do with the `Global.asax`, but I'm not really sure why its getting truncated. My code compiles locally fine, but its only the merge that is messing up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As a shot in the dark:

Is it a slash issue? I vaguely remember MSBuild forcibly requiring a trailing slash on some of its properties.